# Index exceeds maximum length in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I am getting below error. How to fix it? Why am I getting this error?

> Message operation failed. The index entry of length 1526 bytes for the index ix_Emp_no_1 exceeds the maximum length of 900 bytes.

Comment: Straight from the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server "The maximum number of bytes in a clustered index key cannot exceed 900 in SQL Server."

Comment: Because the index entry of length 1526 bytes for the index ix_Emp_no_1 exceeds the maximum length of 900 bytes.

Comment: The combined possible max length of **all** your columns that you're trying to put into an index **CANNOT** exceed 900 bytes. Obviously, in your case - that *is* the case. How to fix it?? Put fewer and smaller columns into your index

Comment: add the script of your table and index

Comment: i used below script.
Create Table T_Index_Test(PRODUCT VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, F_PHY_Name nvarchar(1000) not null CONSTRAINT PK_T_INDEX_TEST PRIMARY KEY(PRODUCT,F_PHY_NAME))
insert into T_Index_Test select 'A0001',cast(replicate('x', 899) as varchar(1000))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never seen this, but I found this article that may help you deal with your situation.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bartd/2011/01/06/living-with-sqls-900-byte-index-key-length-limit/

It sounds like you have a key that is over 900 bytes, a large text field maybe. So you need to find a different way to identify that row. Try to index a different column and include the problem column.

Answer (score 6):

Maximum Bytes per index key

- 900 bytes for a clustered index.
- 1,700 for a nonclustered index

Result and meaning:

- When you have a nchar(450)  because Unicode characters occupy 2 bytes it will equal 900 bytes.
- you can ignore Unicode and use char(900) instead.
- for variable strings types like varchar and nvarchar it seems to be working in the same manner.
- if you have composite key containing multiple columns the sum of them have to have lower bytes than this limitations.

Note : sometimes the SSMS designer does not let you create index larger than 900 bytes (till 1700 bytes) but it is officially supported. you just need to generate the script and run it yourself.

source : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017